# 0 Can we install tensorflow==0.11.0rc0 version in colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Can we install tensorflow==0.11.0rc0 version in colab , as one of the pre-trained model code I use is coded in this version

Answer (score 0):

You can install any version of TensorFlow in google collab.
However, there are specific versions that are available, so you may want to pick from those options . `version 0.11.0rc0` is not currently available.

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.1.0rc0.  #install a tensorflow version
import tensorflow as tf # import tensorflow
print(tf.__version__).  # print tensorflow version
```

Here is the list of available versions as of now.

```
0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0rc0, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0
```